# How set color in ColorPicker in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, modal-dialog, picker

I use CirclePicker from react-color. I have the modal window which contains form, where are ColorPicker. I send to my form info about current color at format hex (#123123). I want to set selected color when user open the form. How can to select a colored circle?

```
const [settingWidget, setSettingWidget] = useState({
    color: '#f44336', //default
  });

 function changeColor(colorChoice, event){
    setSettingWidget({
      color: colorChoice.hex
    });
  }

<div>
      <Modal
        visible={visible}
        title='Edit'
        okText='Save'
        cancelText='Cancel'
        onCancel={onCancel}
        onOk={() => {
              form.resetFields();
              onSave(values);
        }}
      >
        <Form
          {...formItemLayout}
          layout={formLayout}
          form={form}
          initialValues={{
            colorPicker: settingWidget.color,
          }}
        >
          <Form.Item />
          
          <Form.Item name='colorPicker' label='Color'>
            <CirclePicker onChange={changeColor} />
          </Form.Item>

        </Form>
      </Modal>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the color attribute. It will initialize with that specific color.

> Color accepts either a string of a hex color '#333' or a object of rgb or hsl values { r: 51, g: 51, b: 51 } or { h: 0, s: 0, l: .10 }. Both rgb and hsl will also take a a: 1 value for alpha. You can also use transparent.

```js
<CirclePicker onChange={changeColor} color={color}/>
```